# Itunes Connect status Pending Contract

Tags: app-store-connect

to Itunes Connect I have a status of "Pending Contract". In the menu Contracts, Tax, and Banking is the contract for this app not visible. Do I need to be active in this status?.

Comment: in my case my dev license has expired, renewing it made the app go online again

Answer (score 12):

Click on "Agreements, Tax, and Banking" in itunesConnect then request and sign the appropriate contracts. Then you're good to go.

Comment: Here is the [exact section](https://monosnap.com/file/mW4nyT47v43DKnOjCkMfkQMTrmt1yO) @zooster is referring to.

Answer (score 7):

May be you should go to [Member Center](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/) or [Dev Center](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) and Accept the latest(iOS 8) License agreement, then you will be able to renew your contracts for iAds and paid apps again